# Read a file using a bash script

Tags: bash

I need to read a file using a "Do/While" loop.
How can I read the contents as a string?

Here's my code:

```
cat directory/scripts/tv2dbarray.txt | while read line
do
  echo "a line: $line"
done
```

Error:

```
test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.sh: line 4: `done'
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Is there something else in the script? Perhaps another `while` or `if` or an unbalanced quote, brace, bracket or parentheses?

Comment: `# or - it might be copy-pasted (with some rich text, Which is messing up the file itself)` how-why-what-is this I am typing? uhm; it have (put simply) happened to me a bunch--of-times when I copy-pasting code into libreoffice, then copy-pasting it back(having colored the text) so some in-visible characters also get's copied - really weird - but it still is the same problem; 

to solve it you just by-hand type it(cat directory...`)
(for long files this is a problem)
(for short snippets like this one, it's easily and quickly typed)


`Just needed to throw that in for any future explorer`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
cat file | while read line
do
  echo "a line: $line"
done
```

EDIT:

To get file contents into a var use:

```
foo="`cat file`"
```

Comment: test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.sh: line 5: `done'

Comment: Please check this once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459572/replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-contents-copied-from-another-file?noredirect=1#comment99510991_56459572

Answer (score 125):

There's no reason to use `cat` here -- it adds no functionality and spawns an unnecessary process.

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "a line: $line"
done < file
```

To read the content of a file into a variable, use `foo=$(<file)`.
(Note that this trims trailing newlines.)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more times and ensure that it was the top result of every Google search. I phrased this question so many ways over the past hour and everytime until now I found answers along the lines of "use cat". Finally, the sane one line answer (which, unlike cat, simply works.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @gniourf_gniourf -- you learn somthing new every day!

Comment: @AdamLiss @ArtOfWarfare is there a way to define a variable via that method to also keep num. of "things" or "lines" ? like, "for each line do ECHO LINE but also ECHO NUMBER " ?  I don't mean another for or yeah but I thought - do `read` have such a feature? like, read->file line by line's`CONTENTS` into variable_A  and at same time, read->file line by line'S NUMBER into `variable_B` ?

and I used CAPS at times to just make it more detailed, (so, uhm - I do `not  scream`!  :)  ) 

if not; thanks anyway - have a great day!

Comment: @WilliamMartens - Yes, but really quickly you hit the point where you have to ask yourself why you're doing so much in bash and not just using Python or another scripting language. (No, I don't know your answer but I'm sure there is one. Search around on SO - I'm sure it's been asked and answered before. Post a new question if it hasn't been.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare yes; thank you - just wanted to check it. Over n out ️ have a great day! :)

Comment: @WilliamMartens:   

`i=0; while read line; do ((i=i+1)); echo "Line $i: $line"; done < file`   

You could also cheat and use `grep -n` to search for something that will match every line and number the results:   

`grep -n '' file | while read...`   

@ArtOfWarfare I can't help it. My native language is bash. ️   

How  wonderful to see a question and answer that are still relevant 10 years later!

Comment: @AdamLiss **THANKS** Holy.. heavens.. wow - thanks a lot !  Maybe add that to your answer..? as a extra-thing or , yeah - Note I didn't expect to see a reply but in a few decades.. And you just replies TODAY?! :D heh.. made ones day !

cheers! ️ (`it's water`)

Comment: This won't echo the last line if the file does not end with a newline character. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/1091231 for a solution that also works in that case.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
file=path/of/file/location/filename.txt

while IFS= read -r varname; do
    printf '%s\n' "$varname"
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
while read p
do 
echo $p
done <  directory/scripts/tv2dbarray.txt
```