# Replace a string in a file with contents copied from another file

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, terminal

I have figured out and tried replacing strings with the help of `gsed -i` command like this:

```
gsed -i 's/sdkUniqueKey=""/sdkUniqueKey="123"/g' AppConstants.txt
```

Now I want to do the same operation on another string in my file but as my question states, I need to copy the contents from a different file first and then replace a string, something like:

```
gsed -i 's/sdkPrivateKey=""/sdkPrivateKey="contentsCopiedFromAnotherFile"/g' AppConstants.txt
```

One more thing, the contents (to be copied), have next line and white space in it, which I would like to remove before copying. Also it has backslash and forward slashes, hope they don't create any issues while replacing the content). Here is what I am trying to copy:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQDNGillPEfz8d7W
0fyJejF9AYeo8OowcdOcxrpzs4IiXCwPEP1MOHAaOwGTdMwSAeQjw9WOYpE1q+DU
I+Zhh4DVUR8dIdYQtXe+oK/QfhVQMJ3AjTKRvhUmFciGwxXlnLBIkN/ePplNdq9Z
Y5DrSR0lE8X2dD+ZRAkQRpsY8TE48b9f443sbsU4sMvNaxd2XTxe2TLYRvB00w6Q
3lqZiKLzttINBCPoCjhJwBdhcF/LHsCmYhfElPqJxH27BTGBOnbICdmazdnChXQg
3hhsbJmnNDe17Spw0lY
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am able to copy the contents of a file into a variable as well:

```
contents ="`cat fileToBeRead`"
```

All I need is to remove white spaces and new lines from this string and use this "`contents`" variable in my `gsed` command

Comment: `echo $var > $fileToBeRead `is strange, it redirects the value of a variable `var` into file named `$fileToBeRead`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am fairly new to bash and linux, I might have understood wrong.

Comment: you can store the contents you want to replace into a variable, eg. `var=$(grep ...)` and substitute it into your sed command

Comment: Do you want to replace the contents of the $fileToBeRead with the new ones or you want to append them instead?

Comment: I want to copy the contents of "fileToBeRead" and substitute a string in another file with this content.

Comment: If what you posted is your real private key, you should get a new one...

Comment: It's not real one.

Comment: You say you want to remove newlines and white space from the file contents, but you don't say what you want it to look like. I don't think running all the lines of a private key together is going to work very well.

Comment: It does work, I have already tried it.

Comment: contents ="`cat $fileToBeRead`" syntax is deprecated, use contents =$(cat $fileToBeRead) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have properly understood your question, the following should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileToBeRead="key.txt" #Whatever

var=$(tr -d '[:blank:]\n' < $fileToBeRead)
sed -i "s#sdkPrivateKey=\"\"#sdkUniqueKey=\"$var\"#g" AppConstants.txt
```

Since the key contains backslashes/slashes you should use a different separator for sed (e.g. #) or the sentence will be misparsed.

**EDIT:**

```
KEY="$var" perl -pi -e 's/sdkPrivateKey=""/sdkUniqueKey="$ENV{KEY}"/g' AppConstants.txt
```

`perl` can be used instead of `sed` in order to avoid `sed`'s separator issues. Check out @DennisWilliamson's comment below.

Comment: But this assumes that the key doesn't contain pound signs (or any other character you might choose as an alternative `sed` delimiter).

Comment: That's right, but no the problem here IMO. Choosing a good or bad separator  (according to the data to be processed) is up to the OP. May be he can use a non-printable separator (I don't know 100% if this would work in this situation)

Comment: I am getting "-bash: “p.pem”: No such file or directory", for `fileToBeRead=“p.pem” `. While when I do `ls`, I can see that file.

Comment: @nr5 Both the script and the keyfile are in the same dir? Are you sure of being using the real filename?

Comment: I just removed the double quotes and it worked: `fileToBeRead=key.txt`

Comment: I got stuck again. oldkey='somekey' newkey='anotherKey'. Now I want to remove the occurrence of old key with new key, so I tried this: 
perl -pi -e 's/\"${oldKey}\"/\"${trimmedNewKey}\"/g' AppConstants.txt. But nothing happens. Any help ?